# BIOS. LBA mode reading doesn't read sectors

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios, osdev

I'm working on my own bootloader and I'm using QEMU as a test lab to check/debug it. Right now I want to practice with reading of sectors using BIOS extensions. According to the docs QEMU uses SeaBIOS which should support int 13h AH=42h. 
I have this code

```
bits    16                      ; we are in 16 bit real mode

org 0                       ; we will set regisers later

start:  jmp main                    ; jump to start of bootloader


Print:
        lodsb               ; load next byte from string from SI to AL
        or  al, al          ; Does AL=0?
        jz  PrintDone       ; Yep, null terminator found-bail out
        mov ah, 0eh         ; Nope-Print the character
        int 10h
        jmp Print           ; Repeat until null terminator found
PrintDone:
        ret             ; we are done, so return


ReadSectors:

         mov ah,0x42
         mov dl,0x80
         mov si,dap
         int 0x13  
         jc .error
         jmp .exit
.error:
         mov si,msgFailure
         call Print
         cli
         hlt
.exit:  
    ret


 main:

 ;----------------------------------------------------
 ; code located at 0000:7C00, adjust segment registers
 ;----------------------------------------------------

    cli                     ; disable interrupts
    mov     ax, 0x07C0              ; setup registers to point to our segment
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax
    mov     fs, ax
    mov     gs, ax

 ;----------------------------------------------------
 ; create stack
 ;----------------------------------------------------

    mov     ax, 0x0000              ; set the stack
    mov     ss, ax
    mov     sp, 0xFFFF
    sti                     ; restore interrupts
    xor ax,ax
    mov ah,0x41
    xor dx,dx
    mov dl,0x80
    mov bx,0xAA55
    int 0x13
 ;----------------------------------------------------
 ; Display loading message
 ;----------------------------------------------------

    mov     si, msgLoading
    call    Print
    call ReadSectors
    mov si,0x200
    call Print
    cli
    hlt               
dap:
packetSize: db 0x10
reserved:   db 0x0
sectorsNumber:  dw 0x1
buf_seg:    dw 0x0000
buf_off:    dw 0x7E00
lba:        dd 0x0
            dd 0x0

msgLoading  db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Loading Boot Image ", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
msgCRLF     db 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
msgProgress db ".", 0x00
msgFailure  db 0x0D, 0x0A, "ERROR : Press Any Key to Reboot", 0x0A, 0x00

TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0
DW 0xAA55
```

It checks if the extensions are supported using AH=41h function and then reads 1 sector starting from LBA=0h to memory 0000:7E00. 
I'm using gdb to connect to qemu machine to check register and memory. So what I see is that

- int 13h AH=42 returns CF=0, so there is no error
- int 13h AH=41h returns CF=0,CX=7, so it means that BIOS supports extensions. 
  But then I check memory at address 7E00 and I see only zeros, but I expect to see the code of bootloader as it is stored in the LBA=0h sector.

This is how I create disk image

```
nasm bootloader.asm -o ./bin/bootloader.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=./floppy/floppy.img bs=1024 count=1440
dd if=./bin/bootloader.bin of=./floppy/floppy.img conv=notrunc
```

And this is how I run qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -hda ./floppy/floppy.img
```

Can you please help with understanding what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: You used `org 0x07C0`. Isn't it meant to be `org 0x7c00`

Comment: In real mode the linear address is calculated like this Address=Segment*10h+Offset, so 0x07C0*10h = 0x7C00.

Comment: In the disk address packet (DAP) offset is first followed by segment. So `buf_seg:    dw 0x0000`
`buf_off:    dw 0x7E00` should be `buf_off:    dw 0x7E00` `buf_seg:    dw 0x0000` . The reason for this is because x86 is a little endian processor so segment:offset is stored as offset first and segment second.

Comment: When the BIOS transfers control to your bootloader it sets DL to the boot drive number. Rather than hard coding DL to drive 0x80 you should just use the DL value passed to the bootloader by the BIOS.You should consider setting SP to an even number.You use 0x0000:0xFFFF. If you use 0x0000:0x0000 the CPu will wrap around to the top of the segment when the first push is done. After the first push SP would become 0x0000:0xFFFE

Comment: @preciousbetine The `org` directive seems correct with respect to the segment selector OP chose.

Comment: you should insert `org 0x7c00` before `cli`

Comment: @preciousbetine : The `org 0` where he has it is correct, and he is also correct to load the segment registers with 0x07c0. That is because a segment:offset pair of 0x07c0:0x0000 is physical address 0x07c0<<4+0x000=0x07c00. Altrnatively he could have used `org 0x7c00` and set the segments to 0x0000 since 0x0000<<4+0x7c00 also equals = 0x07c00. Both represent the same physical memory address.

Comment: @preciousbetine : with NASM (with the BIN format) the placement of the `otg` doesn't matter. No matter where you place it, it acts as if was at the very beginning.

Comment: @Michael Petch Thanks a lot! It helped. And also now I store DL in memory and then I use it in all int 13h functions. And thanks for recommendation how to set up SP.

Comment: In my previous comment `otg` was meant to be `org`. Simple typo sorry

Comment: Yes, I set up the DS first and then copy DL to memory. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Disk Access Packet (DAP) the segment:offset pair is stored with offset first followed by segment. This is because the x86 is a little endian processor and the pair is stored in reverse order. Your DAP should be changed to:

```
dap:
packetSize: db 0x10
reserved:   db 0x0
sectorsNumber:  dw 0x1
buf_off:    dw 0x7E00              ; Place offset before segment
buf_seg:    dw 0x0000
lba:        dd 0x0
            dd 0x0
```

Comment: I have also seen some (buggy?) BIOSes that require the `ES` register to contain the segment value which is stored in the DAP. These BIOSes ignore the segment value in the DAP and take it from the `ES` register.